# How to use GreenRobot's EventBus in broadcasting events from Service to Activity?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, greenrobot-eventbus

Recently I became aware of EventBus Library. Basically my use case revolves around a service and  an Activity.

Service is used for tracking the changes in the BLE connection.

Activity is used for reporting that connection state to the UI.

How can I achieve the same using the library..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Activity's `onResume` method, register for events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And unregister at `onPause`

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

When service is running and it obtains info regarding BLE, send this info through EventBus:

```
BLEInfo bleInfo = new BLEInfo(... // create some kind of object to aggregate the info about ble connection
EventBus.getDefault().post(bleInfo);
```

Finally, implement the activity's behavior for getting the info:

```
public void onEvent(BLEInfo bleInfo) {
    // update your UI based on bleInfo
}
```